# Angular: data read is undefined when trying to use pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I am trying to paginate a potentially very long list of divs. I have things working fine without the pagination however when I try to implement pagination (using this as a sort of template: http://plnkr.co/edit/81fPZxpnOQnIHQgp957q?p=preview) I receive an error: `TypeError: cannot read property 'slice' of undefined` . As far as I can tell this is an issue involving the `$scope.data` variable since I am calling slice on `$scope.data` . I am not sure how to resolve this and get it working. I will post the working version without pagination followed by the erroneous version with pagination.  The only differences in the controller are from the line `filteredTodos` onward. I am calling `fetchAllSamples()` which populated `$scope.data` before any other work is done with pagination so I'm not sure why it would be undefined. All help is much appreciated.

Erroneous pagination html:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div style="border: 1px solid #000000">
        <div ng-repeat="item in filteredTodos" style="margin-left: 14px">
          <a href="underConstruction.html" style="font-size: 34px; text-decoration: underline">{{item.name}}</a>
          <br> <span style="font-size: 20px">{{item.description}}</span>
          <br>
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <pagination ng-model="currentPage" total-items="data.length" max-size="maxSize" boundary-links="true"> </pagination>
  </div>
</div>
```

and correct non-paginated:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div style="border: 1px solid #000000">
        <div ng-repeat="item in data" style="margin-left: 14px">
          <a href="underConstruction.html" style="font-size: 34px; text-decoration: underline">{{item.name}}</a>
          <br> <span style="font-size: 20px">{{item.description}}</span>
          <br>
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

which use the following controller:

```
app.controller('SamplesQueryController','$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.newSampleName = {
    sampleName: ''
  };

  $scope.attributes = [{
    name: '',
    value: ''
  }];

  $scope.sampleCount = 0;

  $scope.addAttribute = function() {
    var attribute = {
      name: '',
      value: ''
    };
    $scope.attributes.push(attribute);
  }

  $scope.showModal = false;
  $scope.toggleModal = function() {
    $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
  };

  $scope.headerCount = 0;
  $scope.headers = new Array("Id", "Name", "URL", "Description");

  $scope.fetchAllSamples = function() {
    $scope.response = null;
    $scope.method = 'GET';
    $scope.url = '/api/samples';

    $http({
      method: $scope.method,
      url: $scope.url
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.data = response.data;
        angular.forEach(response.data,function(value,key) {
          $scope.sampleCount += 1;
        });
      },
      function(response) {
        $scope.data = response.data || "Request failed";
      }
    );
  };

  $scope.createSample = function() {
    $scope.response = null;
    $scope.method = 'POST';
    $scope.url = '/api/samples';
    $http({
      method: $scope.method,
      url: $scope.url,
      data: JSON.stringify({
        name: $scope.newSampleName.sampleName,
        attributes: $scope.attributes
      })
    }).then(function(response) {
      $scope.fetchAllSamples();
    });
  };
  $scope.fetchAllSamples();
  $scope.filteredTodos = [], $scope.currentPage = 1, $scope.numPerPage = 10, $scope.maxSize = 5;
  $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage),
      end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
    $scope.filteredTodos = $scope.data.slice(begin, end);
  });
}]);
```

Comment: before you `$scope.data.slice(begin, end);` make sure `$scope.data` is not NULL and an array. You are getting this as soon as you load the page right?

Comment: I have added `$scope.data = [];` to the beginning of the fetchAllSamples() method but this results with no errors but an empty table with no divs when I know I have data in $scope.data

Comment: can you verify that `$scope.data = response.data;` actually contains data in your `then`? Also, why are you doing a `foreach` on `response.data` to only increment `$scope.sampleCount`? You could just set `$scope.sampleCount` equal to the length of `response.data` if it does indeed have data.

Comment: yes i can verify that scope.data actually contains data and you're right that is an unnecessary way to get sampleCount

Comment: @Ronnie I noticed that $scope.data is populated however $scope.filteredTodos never gets populated. Not sure why this is as $scope.data is a very long list

Comment: For some reason, when I get to the $scope.$watch, $scope.data is an empty list again. However if I use {{data}} in my html page, then I see my long list of data... not sure why this is happening

Comment: any possibility you can make a fiddle replicating this issue?

Comment: unforuntately I've already trimmed the posted code a ton. These files have so many dependencies that the plunkr would be enormous. I just need to figure out why $scope.data is empty when splice is called but populated anywhere else in the controller. For reference, I get an undefined error on the splice call if I dont call `$scope.data=[]` and if i do use that line then $scope.data is empty on the splice call

Comment: Then I would start putting some `console.log()`s in and map out the workflow of `$scope.data` starting with when it gets populated.